# CAML Query works in U2U CAML Query Builder, but not SharePoint

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I built a CAML query using U2U CAML Query Builder and it works when I execute it in the builder, but when I go to JSOM in SharePoint, I get the entire list and none of the filters from the query work.

Query

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created1' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-10-29T10:07:07Z</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created1' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-11-04T09:07:08Z</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Here is the code that isn't working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function retrieveListItemsInclude() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Incidents');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Created1\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>2014-10-29T10:07:07Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name=\'Created1\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>2014-11-04T09:07:08Z</Value></Leq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query>');
    window.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title, Created1, Severity)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, window.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, window.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nCreated: ' + oListItem.get_item('Created1');
    }

    console.log(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the query with `<View>` tag

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Created1\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>2014-10-29T10:07:07Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name=\'Created1\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>2014-11-04T09:07:08Z</Value></Leq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
```

Comment: Please specify where this differs from the original code, for clarity

Comment: @RobertLindgren updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I looked at that code for such a long time I missed that.